# Как в Excel сравнить 4 столбца по 2-м параметрам

Tags: функции, excel

У меня в Excel есть 4 столбца  A, B, C, D

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa | 10.09.2023 3:52:30 | dd | 26.09.2023 12:52:19 |
| 2 | bb | 13.09.2023 4:15:22 | aa | 10.09.2023 3:50:31 |
| 3 | cc | 19.09.2023 16:03:07 | ee | 19.09.2023 16:03:07 |
| 4 | aa | 10.09.2023 3:45:10 | cc | 18.09.2023 14:36:12 |

Мне нужны общие данные столбцов A и C, с условием что дата в столбце B больше чем в D.

Я попробовала функцию `=IF(AND(COUNTIF(C:C;A1); B1>D:D); 1; 0)`  
Затем через фильтр выбрала все 1, все вроде получилось но в некоторых случаях он считает некоторые строчки как true, даже если дата B меньше чем дата D.

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему эта функция не точно вычисляет, и какой формулой можно получить нужный результат?

Хочу получить такой результат

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa | 10.09.2023 3:52:30 | dd | 26.09.2023 12:52:19 | 1 |
| 2 | bb | 13.09.2023 4:15:22 | aa | 10.09.2023 3:50:31 | 0 |
| 3 | cc | 19.09.2023 16:03:07 | ee | 19.09.2023 16:03:07 | 1 |
| 4 | aa | 10.09.2023 3:45:10 | cc | 18.09.2023 14:36:12 | 0 |

Comment: Функции считают так, как их попросили :)   `B1>D:D` - это формирует массив, формулу вводить как формулу массива.  === *нужны общие данные столбцов A и C*... А по формуле можно понять, что Вам нужно количество... Но тут тоже вопрос: количество при сравнении данных столбца с первой датой? Уточните задачу, покажите требуемый результат.

Comment: мне нужны данные столбца A, которые также есть в столбце C, но при этом чтобы дата B была меньше чем дата D. Например, запись  aa есть в столбце  A и C (в ячейках A1, А4, C2) И так как я хочу все сравнить по A, то А1 и B1 мне подходит, потому что B1>D2, а вот А4 не подходит так как его дата B4<D2

Comment: В итоге что должно быть? Номер строки, в которой нашли подходящие данные? Дата из той строки? А если подходит больше одной строки? Покажите результат.

Comment: добавила в пост какой результат хочу получить.  я хочу получить свой результат как логические данные (1 или 0) в E1: E4

Comment: Если A = C и B > D, то 1. Понятно, когда совпадение с одной строкой. Возможен ли вариант, когда несколько строк, где С совпадает с А? Если да - Успешный результат (1) это когда во всех найденных строках B > D или хотя бы в одной?

Comment: в C дубликатов нет, а в A есть. т.е вы сравниваете данные А с С, и может быть что в А одно и тоже повторяется 5 раз, и поэтому 5 раз идет совпадение с С, но даты же в В меняются и поэтому каждый раз в зависимости от В будет меняться результат

Answer (score 0):

```
=ЕСЛИ(СЧЕТЕСЛИ(C:C;A1);--(B1>ВПР(A1;C$1:D$50;2;));)

=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(--(B1>ВПР(A1;C$1:D$50;2;));)
```

Если все значения А есть в столбце С, можно оставить только сравнение:

```
--(B1>ВПР(A1;C$1:D$50;2;))
```

Comment: =ЕСЛИ(СЧЕТЕСЛИ(C:C;A1);--(B1>ВПР(A1;C$1:D$50;2;));) а можете пожалуйста объяснить эту формулу ? что например означает 2 в конце?

Comment: ВПР(A1;C$1:D$50;2;) - ищем значение А1 в первом столбце диапазона (столбце С) и если находим, возвращаем значение из второго (2) столбца. После двойки есть еще один параметр - условие сравнения. Если нужно точное совпадение с искомым А1, пишем ноль или ничего не пишем(как в формуле). При неточном совпадении там должна быть единица. Но при неточном совпадении диапазон должен быть обязательно отсортирован. Точнее и полнее можно почитать в справке о функции ВПР

Comment: Т.е. нашли "аа" в столбце С, прочитали дату из этой же строки и сравнили ее со значением из В1